# Right-align overflowing text in a left-aligned paragraph

Tags: html, css

I'm working with poetry in a web app and need help with an alignment issue.

Assume I'm working with the following normally left-aligned text:

```
For now I know that all I lived and was
Moved towards this moment of my heart’s rebirth;
I look back on the meaning of myself,
A soul made ready on earth’s soil for thee.
```

As the width of the browser window shrinks (as on mobile), this text may begin to overflow on to the next line like this:

```
For now I know that all I lived and was
Moved towards this moment of my heart’s
rebirth;
I look back on the meaning of myself,
A soul made ready on earth’s soil for
thee.
```

But this doesn't work for poetry. I would really like it to show up as:

```
For now I know that all I lived and was
Moved towards this moment of my heart’s
                               rebirth;
I look back on the meaning of myself,
A soul made ready on earth’s soil for
                                  thee.
```

How can I achieve this with CSS?

Comment: Are you using `<br>` for this?

Comment: Can you share your html?

Comment: @NenadVracar Yes, there's a `<br>` after each line, if that's what you meant.

Comment: May be this would be helpful. [poem with css](http://webdesignernotebook.com/css/styling-a-poem-with-advanced-css-selectors/)

Answer (score 3):

**Yes, ....but No.**

---

Yes, because there is a CSS property that does this: `text-align-last`

[**Per MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align-last)

> The text-align-last CSS property describes how the last line of a block or a line, right before a forced line break, is aligned

No, because support is poor. It's either experimental (and requires the user to have a browser 'flag' enabled) or isn't supported at all.

Only IE Edge and Chrome actually support it natively for desktop browsers.

[**CanIUse.com**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-text-align-last)

```css
.parent {
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: 1em auto;
  padding: 1em;
}
p {
  text-align: left;
  text-align-last: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <p>I wandered lonely as a cloud</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was unaware of `text-align-last`. But I tried it out and it doesn't quite help me here. Per the MDN text you quote, it `describes how the last line of a block or a line, right **before** a forced line break, is aligned`. I need it to work on the line right **after** the line break.

Comment: It actually does what you want it to do provided each line is in it's own element...the definition is a little confusing though, I agree,

Comment: Basically, wrapping is a *soft wrap break* not a "forced line break".. Here's the [**W3C spec**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#forced-line-break)

Comment: In my tests, doing this has the unwanted effect of pushing all the text before the break to the right by default, making it jagged-left. This isn't what I'm looking for: I would like only the overflowing text to stick to the right, the rest should be left-aligned as usual.

Comment: Remove any break tags and use a separate paragraph for each line. It clearly works in Chrome, the demo proves that,

Comment: Does [this](http://imgur.com/RP5asSX) look right to you? This is exactly the effect of the above code in Chrome 47. (I changed width to 300.)

Comment: Without seeing the code I can't comment, but I suspect you still have break tags in there.

Comment: I don't see what unusual effect a `<br>` could have here. But no, I don't; though I just tried mixing it with the `<p>` just for kicks, and all that I see is a bunch of extra line breaks added to the above output.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't quite what you are looking for but I would be tempted to hand-align the poem using `<pre>` and then deploy media queries to adjust the `font-size` and `line-height`:

```css
blockquote pre {
padding: 32px;
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 24px;
}

/* Adjusts font-size and line-height for smartphones */
@media only screen and (min-device-width:320px) and (max-device-width:480px),
only screen and (min-device-width:320px) and (max-device-width:568px) {
blockquote pre {
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 18px;
}
}
```

```html
<blockquote>
<pre>
For now I know that all I lived and was
Moved towards this moment of my heart's rebirth;
I look back on the meaning of myself,
A soul made ready on earth's soil for thee.
</pre>
</blockquote>


<blockquote>
<pre>
For now I know that all I lived and was
Moved towards this moment of my heart's
                               rebirth;
I look back on the meaning of myself,
A soul made ready on earth's soil for
                                  thee.
</pre>
</blockquote>
```

Answer (score -3):

just add a CSS rule and a HTML link to it:
HTML:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet/main.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet/normal.css" media="(min-width: 808px)" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet/mobile.css" media="(max-width: 807px)" type="text/css" />
```

then in the `mobile.css`, add a CSS rule for you poetry

```
#poetry { 
    text-align: left;
}
```